# SEO: Is it necessary to disavow historic / deleted links?

Tags: seo, disavow-links

Using a backlink checker I found hundreds of old spammy links that actually aren't there anymore.

There are probably thousands more that have long since been removed.

Is there any reason I would need to retroactively disavow a link even if the link doesn't exist anymore?   And do historic links still confer link juice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If Google does not know about it, do not worry.*

Backlink sites are extremely slow and inaccurate. It is not uncommon that links that have disappeared remain on these sites for quite a long time. The most accurate view of what links exist for your site comes from Google itself- especially if you are in trouble.

*Do not use these garbage sites. Ignore them. Use the standards that matter; Google and Bing.*

**There is no need to disavow links that Google does not know about and are deleted just because you see them on a junk site.**